Issue: Inconsistent Rendering of Calendar Block in Gmail vs. Outlook
We are experiencing a discrepancy when sending a calendar block in the email body. Gmail automatically generates and attaches an .ics file when a calendar block is present, but Outlook only renders the calendar block without attaching an .ics file.
We are not attaching the .ics file separately; we're only sending the calendar block. While Gmail creates the .ics file from the calendar block, Outlook does not display it.
Is there a known limitation with Outlook's handling of calendar blocks, or is there a solution that can ensure both the calendar block and .ics file are properly handled in both Gmail and Outlook?
when I try to send ics file as an attachment in gmail I receive two ics files and in outlook one. So this cant be a solution
if (customContent) {emailData.content.push(customContent);}
